# Java sockets program hangs on read line

Tags: java, sockets, networking, bufferedreader

I have a server and client program, the client program sends a string to the server by using println() to its PrintWriter. The server thwn tries to read thid from it's BufferedReader by using the readLine() method, however the Server hangs on read line despite the client sending the message. I was wondering if i was doing something wrong here or if it is a line endings issue?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing call **flush()** method of writer.

Comment: Strange, when i did this and disabled autoFlush it works. Wonder why auto flush wasnt working

Comment: @user6817585: it didn't work because you didn't post your code.